# Need to compare two strings with one variable

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, ksh

I have two variable as `model_name` and `status`. Need to check if `model_name` is either in model1 or model2 and `status` is in Failed then have to send mail to users with format 1 else the mail should be sent as the default format.

I tried

```
If [[ $model_name = "model1" ]] -o [[ $model_name = "model2"]] -a [[$status = "Failed" ]] then format1
else Default format 
fi
```

But this didnt worked and Default format  mail is only getting send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-o` and `-a` are not the operators for `OR` and `AND` operations. Simply use `||` and `&&` respectively.

Also you probably forgot a space before `$status`, and there is no capital letter in `if` command.

Your final test line should look like :

`if [[ $model_name = "model1" ]] || [[ $model_name = "model2"]] && [[ $status = "Failed" ]]`

Comment: Thanks... i tried the same but it did not worked.                                                                                    if [ $model_name = "model1" ]] && [ $status = "Failed" ]                                                                   single model_name comaprison is working fine but while doing the or condition its not working

Comment: @user8592197 Even with paranthesis around the `$model_name` comparisons ? Like `([[ $model_name = "model1" ]] || [[ $model_name = "model2"]]) && [[ $status = "Failed"]]` ? Because it's [working for me](http://tpcg.io/ryKHPQ)

Comment: thanks Drosvar ...its working now..Once again thanks